# Python Django Validation Error Message in Dictionary Form

Tags: python, django, rest, validation, django-rest-framework

I am working on certain validation and wants to raise human readable validation Error message in form of dictionary but I am stuck how to pass error messages and dictionary values inside dictionary here is what I have tried in other way:

```
def _is_valid(self):
        boarding_points = self._location.point.all()
        if not set(self._data.get('point')).issubset(set(boarding_points)):
            for boarding_points_name in self._data.get('point'):
                raise ValidationError({'point', boarding_points_name, 'is   not in location', self._location.name}
```

)

above method is surely a wrong approach as it is set and secondly gives validation error message as

```
[
    "{'point', 'is   not in location', 'London', <BoardingPoint: Manchester>}"
]
```

I want error message as

```
{'point': Boarding point: Manchester is not in Location: London}
```

how can I do with python dictionary way to throw readable error message?TT

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way fortunately it is solved

```
def _is_valid(self):
            boarding_points = self._location.point.all()
            if not set(self._data.get('point')).issubset(set(boarding_points)):
                for boarding_points_name in self._data.get('point'):
                    raise ValidationError({
                        'point': _('{} is not associated with location: {}'.format(
                            boarding_points_name.name, self._location.name
                        ))
                    })
```

Comment: Watch out with your translations in this solution. You do formatting before the translation is resolved. Thus no translation will be found once the error is raised, as the formatted message will have no translation within your file. Change it to: `_('{} is not associated with location: {}').format(boarding_points_name.name, self._location.name)`.

Comment: After changing this, makemessages will probably complain, as translators will maybe change the sentence in a way which requires maybe a different order of arguments. Thus you need to add named arguments to your formatting.